# Where to put W3 Total Cache rewrite rules in .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, plugin-w3-total-cache, cache

Should I put them in the following order or the order doesn't matter at all?

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# WordPress default rewrite rules
```

Answer (score 2):

There are rewrite rules involved, so I believe the order does indeed matter. Your suggested order looks correct.